How to authenticate failed EAP-TLS requests on Freeradius
I use Freeradius and certificate-based authentication on my network. Everything works as attended but I also want to authenticate failed EAP-TLS requests to a remediation VLAN, and not reject them.
Currently authentication is rejected if the certificate is revoked or expired.
Is there a way to force the server to accept an revoked or expired certificate ?

this is the expected behavior when a certificate is expired or invalid. We do not support users breaking Policies or even trying to hijack equipment. Update the Equipment and use a valid certificate.
